# How to use gem's model in my models `has_many` or `belongs_to` relationship attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using blogit gem as my bloging solution, but it turns out that only showing blogs is not enough, I need to do couple of things with those blogs. Now I need to create a one to many relationship with blogit databases. I have tried writing:

```
class BlogPost < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blogit_posts
  mount_uploader :avatar, ProductImageUploader
  belongs_to :featured_blog_post
end
```

but at active admin I am getting following error: `uninitialized constant BlogPost::BlogitPost`. I am taking it as a failure to establish that relation.

So what is proper way to use gem's model in my models `has_many` or `belongs_to` relationship attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I need to do is add a `class_name`:

```
  belongs_to :blogit_post, class_name: "Blogit::Post"
```